# Search and create list from a string Python

Tags: python, python-re

I am very new to Python and I am trying to create a list out of string in python.

Input = `"<html><body><ul style="padding-left: 5pt"><i>(See attached file: File1.pdf)</i><i>(See attached file: File2.ppt)</i><i>(See attached file: File3.docx)</i></ul></body></html>"`

Desired Output = [File1.pdf, File2.ppt, File3.docx]

What is the most efficient and pythonic way to achieve this? Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A string is a list in python. To do what you want, you can use the split method.

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser rather than regex

Comment: @LoïcDubois - Strings are sequences, not lists.

Comment: I think I could not summarize it properly. So basically I am seeing some pattern in my string so I thought there might be some efficient way. in my string, File1.pdf, File2.ppt and File3.docx is between the "(See attached file: " and ")</i>". So may be there is a way to search these substrings within the string and get the file names and store in a list. Not sure if these make some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **beatifulsoup**,  which has HTML parsing utils.

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<html><body><ul style="padding-left: 5pt"><i>(See attached file: File1.pdf)</i><i>(See attached file: File2.ppt)</i><i>(See attached file: File3.docx)</i></ul></body></html>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser='html')
>>> files_list = [i.text.split('file: ')[1].replace(')', '') for i in soup.find_all('i')]
>>> print(files_list)
['File1.pdf', 'File2.ppt', 'File3.docx']
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a nice way to do this using a HTML parser like shree.pat18 suggested but here is a quick and dirty way using string.split()

```
Output = [s.split(")")[0] for s in Input.split("file: ")[1:]]
```

By first splitting on "file: " we get list of strings, the first one contains the first part of the original string so we don't care about that one. The others start with the filenames that we want and the first character we don't care about is ")". So split on ")" and take the first part.